# Ajax data is not dispalying

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

jQuery Function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: formsubmission,
    data: Getcity,
    success: function(response){
    var city = '';
    var citylist = response;
    $.each(citylist, function(key, value) {
      alert('each function');
      alert(value.ID);
   });
  }
});
```

JSON data:

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":"1",
      "Name":"Ahmedabad",
      "State":"2",
      "Status":"Open"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"9",
      "Name":"Mumbai",
      "State":"2",
      "Status":"Open"
   }
]
```

My jQuery function is not alerting JSON data and it not alerting each function is not working how can I resolve this error? sorry for my weak English.

Comment: Try alert(response)  at the first line of success handler. Does it show something?

Comment: yes it displaying data

Comment: Then try var citylist=$.parseJSON(response)

Comment: You get results as a plain text, until you set type of response to "json", so you need to additionally apply parseJSON to convet returned text to json object

Comment: Yes now it working thanks for support

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type to method

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: formsubmission,
    data: Getcity,
    success: function(response){
    var city = '';
    var citylist = $.parseJSON( response );
    $.each(citylist, function(key, value) {
      alert('each function');
      alert(value.ID);
   });
  }
});
```

Comment: it's not working can you please help me now how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you check what error you are getting? For me, above code is working with URL change

Comment: brother please update your answer sure than I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop it might also help to do alert(key) and alert(value) to check what you are having at that moment.

Comment: brother can you please write a programm?

Answer (score 0):

Bro while working with jQuery you need to write every thing in

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  });
```

Just try to keep your ajax call inside ready function and let me know about the result...Hope this helps...:)